# Remove Labels from Nokia Maps "Here"

Tags: api, maps, here-api

I am using the Javascript Api for Nokia "Here". I don't want the Labels of the country, state, city, etc appear on my map.

This issue can be resolved by changing the map type to "Satellite_plain". But I have restriction of using the "Terrain" view in my project.

http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/api-explorer

Answer (score 2):

The list of supported map types can be found in the API Documentation [here](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics/changing-map.html). Unfortunately `TERRAIN_PLAIN` (or something like that) is not a supported map type - only satellite imagery without labels is available "out of the box".

You will have to use the `ImgTileProvider` class to create your own tile overlay and hook it up to a Tile Map Server (**TMS**). The tiles you are after are actually the terrain **basetiles** as defined in the **Map Tile API** ( the documentation can be found [here](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile) - log-in required) You can then use the terrain base tiles as a **TMS** as shown below:

```
function getTerrainTileUrl (zoom, row, column) {
    // This uses the CIT server. Replace with LIVE when ready.
    return "http://1.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/basetile/newest/terrain.day/"+
        zoom +"/" + column + "/" + row + "/256/png8?app_id=" + nokia.Settings.app_id +
        "&app_code=" + nokia.Settings.app_code;
}


function addTileOverlayToMap (map){
    tileProviderOptions = {
        getUrl: getTerrainTileUrl,
        max:20,
        min:1
    };
    terrainOverlay = new 
            nokia.maps.map.provider.ImgTileProvider(tileProviderOptions);
    map.overlays.add(terrainOverlay);
}
```

The result (compared with an ordinary `TERRAIN` map can be seen below:

[image: Edinburgh]

[Working Example](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/examples.html#map-tiles__aerial-map-tile-styles-and-modes)